# How do I calibrate the temperature of my hotend?

Tags: calibration, hotend, wanhao, monoprice-maker-select

I'm using a Monoprice Maker Select v2 (a Monoprice-branded Wanhao i3 duplicator) and would like to calibrate temperature readings for my hotend.

I used a thermal probe on my multimeter to determine the hotend is running about 5 degrees C above it's reported temperature (setting it to 200 degrees reads 205 on the multimeter).  I measured this by placing the thermal problem partly into the hole where the printers thermistor resides.

I use Marlin 1.9 for firmware and ideally would calibrate it there--I'd prefer the readouts to be accurate rather than relying on offsets to compensate.  What's the process for recalibrating the hotend temperature readings?

Comment: While interesting, it's not needed. A 5-10 °C error has little effect if you use the suggested temperatures and has zero effect if you pick the best temperature with temperature towers (and strength testing, if you have the equipment). Even if you have PTFE hotend setting 250 °C and getting 255-260 °C won't destroy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a calibrated temperature sensor, it is a question what the temperature will be.

Actually it doesn't really matter what the temperature exactly is, you just need to find the sweet spot for your filaments on your machine. With respect to reported temperatures by others, your settings may differ a little, but that does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature from thermosensors gets collected as a resistance value that changes with temperature. The chip in your board decides the temperature from this value based on a temperature-resistance table.

If you are using Marlin Firmware, the setting which table is referenced by your machine to get its values is written under the header Thermal Settings inside `Confinguration.h`.