# 3DBenchy's bow prints out of alignment

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting

I'm new to 3D printing, but I've solved all of my problems except for this rough surface shown in the image of a Benchy  print:

[image: Benchy showing printing defects]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

- Printer (new): Raptor 2 (400x400x700 mm)
- Bed Temp: 65 °C
- Extruder Temp: 210 °C
- Filament: PLA (1.75 mm) right out of the package (came with printer from
  Formbot)
- 200 degrees extruder; 60-degree hotbed - print success, bow issue
  persists. speed: 100
- fade height: 0
- nozzle: 200
- bed: 60
- fan speed: 255
- flow: 100 probe offset: -1.4

[image: Best results so far: 200°, 60° hotbed, 50 speed. Best yet settings still need to be tweaked. Not sure where to go?]

[image: Best results so far: 200°, 60° hotbed, 50 speed. Best yet settings still need to be tweaked. Not sure where to go?]

Comment: Hi Harrison, welcome to 3D Printing.SE!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calibration improvement of the prusa I3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7671/calibration-improvement-of-the-prusa-i3)

Comment: You should also specify print speed (see my answer) and layer height.

Comment: Too much temperature, try at 195 °C.

Comment: Best results so far: 200°, 60° hotbed, 50 speed. Best yet settings still need to be tweaked. Not sure where to go?

Comment: sadly the new pictures are barely visible. More light is needed, and an indicator which benchy you mean. is the white the one before and the black the new one? it would be better to have both in the same color.

Answer (score 3):

You print too hot and probably with not enough cooling. These typical defects are caused by too much heat input into your model. You see this best at the overhang of the bow of Benchy, it should be smooth like the bottom part of the side of your Benchy. It clearly shows heat induced defects. Lower the temperature at least 10 °C. Know that PLA usually is printable at about 190 °C, also 65 °C for the hotbed is quite high, Depending on the surface you could aim for a temperature between 50 - 60 °C,

Comment: At 190°, the print was terrible. Pictured below was printed at 200°, 60° hotbed, 50 speed. Best yet settings still need to be tweaked.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the blower on the extruder was not plugged in at the factory. Now it's printing fine. Thank you all for the help and support. [image]

Comment: totally missed that the fan could be off! but the temp drop surely did increase the print quality on its own already.

Comment: As I said I'm my answer: `with not enough cooling.`! Good that you found the plug! :)

Answer (score 2):

The artifact your bow clearly shows is usually a result of very high print temperature - the filament sags unevenly as it is not cooling to solidification fast enough.

You might want to reduce your print temperature for PLA a little. Try one or two 5° steps. I print my PLA usually at 200 °C, some blends even lower. Do the same for the print bed - 60 °C is the usual temperature in many machines.

When I unpack 210 °C that's only in conjunction with 100 % infill and deliberate over-extrusion for what would be best described as a "cast-solid" result. It's because under that condition I want the filament to melt and merge with everything super tight.

It also might help to change the print cooling geometry to better cool the printed parts - and check if all fans are on.

Answer (score 2):

If you printed Benchy upright, this is an overhang. You didn't state the print speed that you used, but I found that I can **improve overhang quality considerably by printing them slower**.

If you're otherwise satisfied with the print quality, you probably don't want to waste time by printing the whole model slower. If you're using Ultimaker Cura there is a setting in the *Experimental* section (don't worry, it works fine) to print only overhangs slower:

[image: cura settings]

(Those are very conservative settings, a larger angle, like 30°, would probably be fine, too.)

Comment: My speed was 100. Reduced to 50 for most successful print see pic below.

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-compile the gcode, sometimes the slicer "freaks out" whilst writing the file. Which slicer are you using? (Cura, Slic3r, Repetier, etc.)

I sometimes have that errors, and giving that they do seem quite consistent in shape in the pics I would say that's the issue.